# Rbind list of vectors with differing lengths

Tags: r, performance, dplyr, data.table, rbind

I am new to R and I am trying to build a frequency/severity simulation. Everything is working fine except that it takes about 10min to do 10000 simulations for each of 700 locations.
For the simulation of one individual location, I got a list of vectors with varying lengths and I would like to efficiently rbind these vectors, filling in NAs for all non-existing values. I would like R to return a data.frame to me. 
So far, I used rbind.fill.matrix after converting the vectors in the list to matrices of 1 row. However, I am hoping that I could use something like bind_rows (dplyr) or rbindfill but I don't know how to transform the vectors into something that I could use for these functions. Thank you in advance for your help!

```
set.seed(1223)

library(data.table)

numsim = 10

rN.D <- function(numsim) rpois(numsim, 4) 
rX.D <- function(numsim) rnorm(numsim, mean = 5, sd = 4)

freqs <- rN.D(numsim)
obs <- lapply(freqs, function(x) rX.D(x))
#obs is the list that I would like to rbind (efficiently!) and have a data.frame returned to me
```

Answer (score 3):

We can append `NA`s at the end to make the `length` same for each of the `list` elements and then do the `rbind`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(obs, `length<-`, max(lengths(obs))))
as.data.frame(out) # if we need a data.frame as output
```

---

or using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
obs %>%
   set_names(seq_along(.)) %>% 
   stack %>% 
   group_by(ind) %>% 
   mutate(Col = paste0("Col", row_number())) %>% 
   spread(Col, values)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I will definitely remember these two options for the future!

Comment: To do it vertically, replace `rbind` by `cbind`

Answer (score 2):

> Everything is working fine except that it takes [too long] to do [`numsim`] simulations

If your real application uses `rnorm` or similar, you can make a single call to it:

```
set.seed(1223)
numsim = 3e5
freqs = rN.D(numsim)
maxlen = max(freqs)
m = matrix(, maxlen, numsim)
m[row(m) <= freqs[col(m)]] <- rX.D(sum(freqs))

res = as.data.table(t(m))
```

I am filling the data the "wrong way" (with each simulation on a column instead of a row) and then transposing since R fills matrix values using ["column-major" order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order).

---

If you need to use `lapply`, here's a benchmark for the final step:

```
set.seed(1223)

library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(purrr)
library(data.table)

numsim = 3e5

rN.D <- function(numsim) rpois(numsim, 4) 
rX.D <- function(numsim) rnorm(numsim, mean = 5, sd = 4)

freqs <- rN.D(numsim)
obs <- lapply(freqs, function(x) rX.D(x))

system.time({
tidyres = obs %>%
   set_names(seq_along(.)) %>% 
   stack %>% 
   group_by(ind) %>% 
   mutate(Col = paste0("Col", row_number())) %>% 
   spread(Col, values)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   16.56    0.31   16.88     

system.time({
    out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(obs, `length<-`, max(lengths(obs))))
    bres = as.data.frame(out)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.50    0.05    0.55 

system.time(
    dtres <- setDT(transpose(obs))
)
#    user  system elapsed 
#    0.03    0.01    0.05
```

The last approach is fastest compared to the other two (both from @akrun's answer).

*Comment.* I would recommend using only data.table or tidyverse. Mixing and matching will get messy very quickly. When I was setting this example up, I saw that `purrr` has it's own `transpose` function, so if you loaded packages in a different order, code like this can give different results without warning.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Now, everything is working perfectly and it takes just about 40 seconds to run the entire simulation. I used the single-call option. However, I changed the code so that I don't have to transpose the Matrix at the end. This made the frequency/severity modelling a lot faster again. Because the severities are now being filled in a bit differently, the results sligthly differ but this is just the monte carlo error. Or was there a specific reason you created the Matrix the "wrong way around" in the first place?

Comment: @Leon231000 Cool, glad to hear it's helpful! Yeah, I just created it that way due to how R treats vectors and matrices: `m[w] <- v` drops values of `v` into `m` in "column-major" order. (I've edited that explanation in above.)